# Batch command FOR Loop to load MySQL Data - (was unexpected at this time)

Tags: mysql, for-loop, batch-file

I am in trouble with FOR LOOP command using a batch file...

Let's see if someone knows how can I solve this issue, because I can not figure out how to solve it. My .bat file is more less like example below...

```
ECHO 'Initializing data loading'

FOR %%I In (C:\TempFolder\*.csv) DO ( 

    ECHO '%%~nxI'

    mysql.exe -h dbInstance -uUser -pPass dbase --local-infile -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"%%~nxI"' INTO TABLE table1 CHARACTER SET Latin1 COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES" 

    mysql.exe -h dbInstance -uUser -pPass dbase "OPTIMIZE TABLE table1"

)
```

My output:

```
C:\DtImport>ECHO 'Initializing data loading'
'Initializing data loading'
as was unexpected at this time.
```

If i execute only the first mysql command, it works fine... Just, when I try to execute more than one command, I ve got this error.

This is the output when I remove the second mysql command as It was on example above

```
C:\DtImport>test
'Initializing data loading';
'EXP_1997.csv'
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

'EXP_1998.csv'
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

Someone can help me with this issue?

All .bat file below

```
 @echo off

ECHO 'Movendo arquivos que serão utilizados para carga...'


ECHO 'Iniciando carga. Aguarde!'

FOR %%I In (C:\DtImport\*.csv) DO ( 

ECHO '%%~nxI'

    mysql.exe -h dinstance -uUser -pPassword dataBase --local-infile -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"%%~nxI"' INTO TABLE temp_table CHARACTER SET Latin1 COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES" 

mysql.exe -h dinstance -uUser -pPassword dataBase -e "INSERT INTO imp_table (select REPLACE(CONCAT(TRIM(col1),'-',TRIM(col2),'-1'),'\"', ''), REPLACE(TRIM(col3),'\"', ''), REPLACE(TRIM(col4),'\"', ''), REPLACE(TRIM(col5),'\"', ''), REPLACE(TRIM(col6),'\"', ''), REPLACE(TRIM(col7),'\"', ''), REPLACE(TRIM(col8),'\"', ''), REPLACE(TRIM(col9),',','.'), REPLACE(TRIM(col10),',','.'), REPLACE(TRIM(col11),',','.') FROM temp_table)"

mysql.exe -h dinstance -uUser -pPassword dataBase -e "DELETE FROM temp_table"

mysql.exe -h dinstance -uUser -pPassword dataBase -e "OPTIMIZE TABLE temp_table"


) 
ECHO 'TERMINADO'

PAUSE
```

Comment: What are the real world file names it is trying to process?  I am having a hard time following the quotes you are using.  They don't seem to be correct.

Comment: *"My .bat file is more less like example below"* - That isn't going to cut it. We need to see the exact code. The code you posted cannot possibly give the error you report. Your error message occurs immediately after the initial ECHO statement, implying the entire loop below was unable to be parsed. Your posted code does not have an "as" token, so it cannot give that error.

Comment: Hi guys! I mean that there are some instructions below, but only ECHO stuff... like echo 'Process Files Terminated'. The real name of files are EXP_1997.csv and EXP_1998.csv. Sometimes, I try to load other files (same format bur different names also). The piece of code that outputs the error is that one

Comment: @Gustavo_Oliveira - I cannot reproduce your error with your posted code. Just looking at the code I can tell it can't give your error, and I also copied the code and ran it. It definitely does not give the `as was unexpected at this time` batch parsing error. There must be something else important that you are not showing.

Comment: In other words, the error is not where you think it is.

Comment: I will copy and paste all .bat file... Thank you very much